# Regex Match phrases with or without quotation

Tags: javascript, regex

im new to regular expressions and i want to build an expression that finds the below pattern:

We have the string:

```
"'Hello world',dude, 'Somethings, never, turn and go', bye"
```

I want a regular expression that gives this result:

```
['Hello world',dude,'Somethings, never, turn and go',bye]
```

Basically, splitting the string on comma but keeping the phrases with quotes that have comma as a whole.

I tried this ('\s*,\s*') but doesnt work.

Comment: Use `eval(s.replace(/^/, "\[").replace(/$/, "]"))` but before that you shoud have declared `dude` and `bye`

Comment: @ArtyomVancyan Wait i might not have been clear enough. I want to give as a result an array not a string with brackets. Basically, splitting the string on comma but keeping  the phrases with quotes that have comma as a whole.

Comment: Maybe `(?<=')\s*,\s*|\s*,\s*(?=')`?

Comment: This looks like csv. Use a csv parser

Answer (score 2):

I think you want something like:

```js
const regex = /(?:\'.*?\')|(?:\w+)/g;

const str = "'Hello world',dude, 'Somethings, never, turn and go', bye";

console.log(str.match(regex));
```

Comment: You can omit the non capture groups here `(?:` You can write it as `'[^'\n]*'|\w+`

Comment: This will get more complicated if there can be escape sequences inside the single quoted strings. Nad even more if there can be escape sequences outside of single quoted strings.

Comment: This wont work for the case 'Hello world's'

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try `(?<=')\s*,\s*|\s*,\s*(?=')`

```js
let s = "'Hello world',dude, 'Somethings, never, turn and go', bye";
let arr = s.split(new RegExp(String.raw`(?<=')\s*,\s*|\s*,\s*(?=')`, 'g'));
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: "dude, 'Somethings, never, turn and go'", are not splitted. Also the positive lookbehind may not be supported in all browsers

Comment: Yeah just noticed. Let me rework this. @Nick

Comment: You can also use a literal in this case as you are not dynamically creating a regex `let arr = s.split(/(?<=')\s*,\s*|\s*,\s*(?=')/);`

Comment: Right, even better! I'll leave my answer as is, and you keep the comment down to add value @Thefourthbird.

Comment: the positive lookbehind may not be supported in all browsers

Comment: @JvdV if i add this string "'Hello world',dude, Somethings, never, turn and go, bye"  it gives this result ["'Hello world'", 'dude, Somethings, never, turn and go, bye'] which is wrong. It doesnt split the other values separated by comma