# Regex Match splitting simple words and quotation words by comma

Tags: javascript, regex

im new to regular expressions and i want to build an expression that finds the below pattern:

I have the string:

```
"'Hello world',dude, 'Somethings, never, turn and go', bye"
```

I want a regular expression that gives this result:

```
['Hello world',dude,'Somethings, never, turn and go',bye]
```

Basically, splitting the string on comma but keeping the phrases with quotes that have comma as a whole.

I have this regex:

```
let s = "'Hello world',dude, 'Somethings, never, turn and go', bye";
let arr = s.split(/(?<=')\s*,\s*|\s*,\s*(?=')/g);
console.log(arr)
```

If i add this string `"'Hello world',dude, Somethings, never, turn and go, bye"` it gives this result `["'Hello world'", 'dude, Somethings, never, turn and go, bye']` which is wrong. It doesnt split the other values separated by comma. How do i fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seen your [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72911051/9758194) question. Coincidentally it showed comma's right after or before the single quote. Hence the "wrong" answer back there. In this case, maybe look for balanced single quotes ahead:

```js
let s = "'Hello world',dude, Somethings, never, turn and go, bye";
let arr = s.split(/\s*,(?=(?:[^']*'[^']*')*[^']*$)\s*/);
console.log(arr)
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/d9qGsM/1).

Answer (score 2):

You can use split with a capture group to keep the split values for `'...'` and using an alternation to split on `,` between optional whitespace chars.

As split can give empty items in the resulting array, you can remove those with `filter(Boolean);`

Also matching escaped single quotes:

```
('[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*')|\s*,\s*
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oDhVxk/1).

```js
let s = "'Hello world',dude, 'Somethings, never, turn and go', bye";
let arr = s.split(/('[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*')|\s*,\s*/g).filter(Boolean);
console.log(arr)
```